# Visual Studio: where to find "browse with"?

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I have installed Visual Studio 2012 and I opened my project from 2010 in the new version. But when I run my web application, it runs in Chrome. In 2010, you can right click on the project and choose "browse with" to change the web borwser. 
In 2012, it is not in the right click menu, but in a toolbar:
[image]

But I don't have this toolbar and I don't find it. Can someone help me to find it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you mean "I don't have this toolbar?"
Go here `View`->`Toolbars`->`Standard`

Answer (score 0):

You have to have a file of the correct type (aspx, html, cshthml, etc.) selected in the Solution Explorer, in order to see the toolbar.